# Behavior of Windows Containers under NAT networking mode

Tags: windows, docker, networking, containers

When I launch a Windows Server Core container running an IIS website with port 80 exposed I can't connect to is using localhost.  Instead I have to run docker exec -it  ipconfig to get the IP assigned to the container and then use that IP in the browser on the local machine.  This behavior differs from Linux where you can connect to the container over localhost.  Why is there a difference in behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The lack of loopback for Docker Windows containers running on Windows Server is a known limitation. This blog post has details: https://blog.sixeyed.com/published-ports-on-windows-containers-dont-do-loopback/